# Prevent state from being rolled back during an error (transactional)

Tags: state, transactional

We're writing a proxy extrinsic that dispatches a child call and consumes a 'free call'. We want to return the error of the child call to the user, but we want to consume a free call regardless.

Since I believe transactions are now transactional by default (ie rollback on error), what's the best way to return the results of the call to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you cannot prevent the state from being rolled back on an error.

Did you have a look at the `pallet-utility` pallet?
The [`force_batch`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/07e1b6d72747f3cde49e85e4ff68ff158daebe16/frame/utility/src/lib.rs#L464) call has a similar semantic where errors are reported through events. It does not abort on an error but rather emits them as events. The respective event definitions look like this:

```rust
/// A single item within a Batch of dispatches has completed with no error.
ItemCompleted,

/// A single item within a Batch of dispatches has completed with error.
ItemFailed { error: DispatchError },
```

It then emits these events depending on the result of a previous dispatch:

```rust
if let Err(e) = result {
    Self::deposit_event(Event::ItemFailed { error: e.error });
} else {
    Self::deposit_event(Event::ItemCompleted);
}
```

So you could probably define similar events for `FreeCallConsumed` and `ChildCallFailed`.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid using Events as they are noisy and client has to manually find them (vs returning the result to them), but it looks like subxt's [`wait_for_finalized_success`](https://docs.rs/subxt/latest/subxt/tx/struct.TxProgress.html#method.wait_for_finalized_success) makes it easy to return the events associated with a transaction. Thanks!

Comment: You kind of have to use events, since a `CallConsumed` could also happen through a different Extrinsic, eg `utility::batch`. So the only way to notice that is to use event and subscribe in the client. There was a similar Q here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5330/monitoring-transfers-and-keep-transfer-alive